# Using FME Stringpadder

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

Trying to use this in a workbench and not getting the output i'd expect, i.e. no apparaent padding in the output.

The SAFE documention seems inadequate:
https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME-Form-Documentation/FME-Transformers/Transformers/stringpadder.htm
Original value: "hello"
Pad Width: 10
Side to Pad: Left
Resulting value: "     hello"

As the parameters exposed in the Stringpadder transformer are more numerous and differently named:

Attributes = I specified the field i'd like padded

Desired String Length = "8"
Side to pad = "Left"

Pad Character = "8" but no idea what this does!

Pad Empty String = "yes" because if it's empty, i still want it padded, right...?

But the output has two spaces, which I believe are the spaces i have specified in the .csv as the delimiter.

I don't understand how this is supposed to work, and google/youtube haven't rendered any working examples.

Answer (score 2):

In the simple workspace the text (hello) is padded by the character %
as hello (5 digits) by the Stringpadder is told to pad by 7 digits.
the Stringpadder adds two extra %% (percentage characters).

**hello%%** is the result

[image]